# Proportional Resizing using BorderLayout in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, border-layout

I am trying to create a GUI in which has three main panels for a text-based game: the leftmost panel for your stats/inventory, the center panel will be for a text pane that displays the story and a text field to type your commands, and the rightmost pane contains quest and mission information. I set the main content pane to have a BorderLayout and added JPanels to the west, center, and east positions (no components added to the panels yet). The center panel takes up most of the space, so I set the east's and west's panels' preferredSize width to be 200, which looks great proportionally for the size of the JFrame (800x500). When maximising the window, however, the east and west panels remain at 200 rather than scaling up proportionally, making it seem small compared to the center panel. When resizing the width of the window to be smaller than 800, the east and west panels remain 200 while the center panel gets smaller, to the point of the east and west panels overlapping. I was wondering if it would be possible to use BorderLayout's west, center, and east positions to scale proportionally upon resizing rather than just the center resizing up and down.
Thank you much for your time!

Edit:
Here are a couple snapshots to show the GUI. It is saying I do not have enough reputation to include images on my posts, so I can only include the hyperlinks to them.
The first image shows the frame at 800x500, the default size (blank space at left and right of the center panel are empty JPanels). The second image shows the GUI maximised (left and right panels remaining at 200).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: a snapshot or image says a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> scale proportionally upon resizing rather than just the center resizing up and down.

I suggest you to use [`GridBagLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) where you can set the width and height of the components in percentage defining different constraints of [GridBagConstraints](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html)

See *Swing Tutorial* on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)